# Set theory list all possible elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I just started learning set theory.I have a question I need to answer for revision. I missed a bit of my lecture so i'm a little lost and I have yet to receive my textbook.

The question is: "Write [–3..1] as a set by explicitly listing all its elements.  "

Just wondering how that works?

Comment: My gut reaction would be that this is impossible because $[-3,1]$ represents the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $-3\leq x\leq 1$. The fact that you are asked to do it, though, suggests to me that this is some special notation introduced in your course, possibly the set of all **integers** between $-3$ and $1$. If so, I would point out that I would "explicitly list" the set $[5..8]$ like so: $\{5,6,7,8\}$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to ask the professor. :)

Comment: @Arturo: $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid -3\le x\le 1\}$ is not explicit, I take it?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Note that the OP wrote $[-3..1]$, not $[-3,1]$.

Comment: @Asaf: It's not a way of "explicitly **listing** all the elements", no.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, which is what leads me to believe it's some sort of "local" notation; sorry I didn't make that clear in my comment (note I used the OPs notation in the last part).

Answer (score 6):

If $n$ and $m$ are integers with $n\le m$, the two-dots notation $[n..m]$ commonly denotes the set of integers between $n$ and $m$ inclusive: $[n..m] = \{k \in \mathbb{Z}:n \le k \le m\}$. If that’s the convention that your class is using $-$ and it’s common in computer science, so it’s not unusual in discrete math courses $-$ then $[-3..1] = \{-3,-2,-1,0,1\}$.